# google-chrome browser not loaded filtered websites when vpn is on, but public ip changed

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-22.04

**Hi everyone**
my conditions:

- I live in Iran and many websites are filtered by the government.
- us windows and ubnutu22.04 OS.
- use last google-chrome browser.
- use VPNs (OpenVPN and open connect).

**My problem: **
when I am in Linux and VPN is on, Mozilla-firefox is ok and works properly, but my goolge-chrome not working for filtered websites, and working for others.
A strange problem is that my public IP changed to another country and I tested it by my IP address website and two more related sites.
It is worth noting that this problem does not occur in windows's chrome.

**What I did:**
I removed google-chrome completely by `sudo apt purge google-chrome && rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome` and reinstalled the last version.

My question is that, How is it possible and why does it occur, please help me.
*Thanks so much*

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently.

Using a VPN, Firefox would work correctly and Chrome would not work for some domains but it would work for others.

This may be caused by the VPN correctly configuring IPv4 but not IPv6 (and Firefox using IPv4 and Chrome using IPv6).

Easiest solution: Disable IPv6, validate and then correct the IPv6 configuration.